# Multiple Backreferences in Matcher.replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, backreference

`Matcher.replaceAll()` with a **single** [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) works great (i.e. `Matcher.replaceAll("$2")`).

But I haven't been able to make it work with two or more backreferences, e.g. `Matcher.replaceAll("$1$2")`.

Does `Matcher.replaceAll()` support multiple backreferences at all? If so, what is the proper syntax to use it?

Comment: Matcher.replaceAll("$1$2") should work. You're doing something wrong

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String) Nothing strange here. Probably your second backreference is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine. The following snippet:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)(.)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab");
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$2$1"));
```

will print:

```
ba
```

Comment: You are all correct. The syntax I used was the right one, but I failed to assign the return value from `Matcher.replaceAll("$1$2")` to the output string. All is well now. Thanks!